# Find the common difference, value of Z & the first term of the arithmetic progression.

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic-progressions

[image]

How to find the common difference the  value of z & the first term.

Any Ideas on how to begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since series is in A.P $$22+4d = 42$$
Which gives $$d = 5$$
After knowing d you can solve for others easily.
d is common to difference.